# Can you access the data object from the current page from a VodaPay Mini-Program?

Tags: vodapay-miniprogram

I have a modal component in my VodaPay Mini-Program, the logic for showing/hiding is in the page that contains the modal component. Is it possible to hide my modal from the component itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to hide your component through the data as well, inside of your component, you can use the `this.setData` method to set the components data which can be used to override the props.

However, do this with caution as the component data will take priority over the props that are passed into the component so you may end up with a bug where you are unable to open the prop from the page again.

You can use the `didUpdate` callback on the component to work around this

**Alternatively**

You can use the `this.$page` inside of the component to get access to the page object, however this causes a large amount of coupling between the page and component and if you use it to control the data in the page you need to know the name used by the page that controls the visibility of the page